# TestCafe: How to wait for a specific element to appear in the dom?

Tags: e2e-testing, testcafe, e2e

I am writing some e2e tests with TestCafe, I am using the `t.wait` mechanism to wait for elements to appear on the page and in the dom, like this :

```
await t.wait(10000);
let sel=Selector("div").withAttribute('data-testid', 'something');
// continue with the test
```

This approach fails sometimes, and the test fails. 
Is there a way to wait for that exact element to appear on the page ? Once the element appears, continue executing the test. I thought of doing something like this :

```
let sel=Selector("div").withAttribute('data-testid', 'something');
while (!sel.exists && !sel.visible) {
continue
}
// continue with the test
```

But there are obvious issues with this method, and it's not very elegant.
So, does anyone else know a better solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [timeout option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402756/reference/test-api/selector/constructor#optionstimeout) for Selector. For example:

```js
let sel=Selector("div", { timeout: 10000 }).withAttribute('data-testid', 'something');
```